# Why does this error occur when I initialize Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies

> Supplied string module notation 'com.google.gms.google-services4.3.15' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.

I am trying to find the solution, I am waiting for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the string module notation

'com.google.gms.google-services4.3.15' is invalid. The correct format for

dependency notations in Gradle typically includes the group, name, and

version.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```